# How can I set text margins in UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` but text in it is align to the bottom but I want there will be a margin from the bottom like this:

----------------

some text

----------------

If I have a `UITextField` I can use `editingRectForBounds:`. But what about `UITextView` how can I achieve this functionality with it? ANY solution will be appreciated. And ,please, don't advice me to use `UITextField` instead! I need `UITextView`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have You tried `yourTxtView.contentInset` property ?

Comment: This question has now a better and more popular alternative here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065693/how-to-set-content-inset-for-uitextview-in-ios

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For iOS 6, try this:

```
TxtView =[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 250, 70)];
    TxtView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    TxtView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    TxtView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    TxtView.scrollEnabled=YES;
    TxtView.editable=YES;
    TxtView.contentSize=TxtView.frame.size;
    TxtView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    TxtView.contentInset    = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4,0,-4,0);  
    TxtView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    TxtView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    TxtView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Here, Inset is where you can give padding like values in textview. textview height is autoresizing so it will be changed according to text.

Comment: Use textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10);

Answer (score 24):

For a UITextView in iOS 7, use this:

textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);

Comment: This was the answer I went with. Seems the best solution for anything iOS7 and above.