# How to set content inset for UITextView in ios

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextview, uiedgeinsets

I'm having a UITextView and set content inset as

`[atextView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)];`

This code working in iOS 6.1 and below, but nothing happens in iOS 7.0.

Comment: Is there a way to do this **IN STORYBOARD** ?!

Comment: did you tried updated answer?

Comment: Yes there is , check my solution below Joe Blow

Comment: @BencePattogato thanks for the update.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

got answer:

```
[atextView  setTextContainerInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7, 0, 0)];
```

fixed my problem.

And in Swift...

```
@IBOutlet var tv:UITextView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    tv.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

**UPDATE: another option to do that.**

```
UIView *spacerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
[msgtext setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[msgtext setLeftView:spacerView];
```

Comment: hey @murugha23 , I need you help on how you solved textview setContentInset problem in IOS7

Comment: replace `setTextContainerInset` instead of `setContentInset`. If you want to provide previous versions of ios, then check a condition reg., current device system version

Comment: it would be good if you can provide me a sample code of your class,including keyboard and textview's various methods ,so i can I have clear idea

Comment: actually whats your problem ? is it setting improperly or completely not setting?

Comment: Yes I am posting question and posting link soon

Comment: Note that you should only use one or the other.  Using both together will result in undesirable additive behavior.

Comment: before using above code i will check condition for ios version

Comment: What I've discovered is that there is some odd (buggy) interaction between the setTextContainerInset UIEdgeInsets values. I was able to get the behavior I wanted as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422578 I'd recommend (blindly) messing around with the 4 values to try and find an acceptable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and maybe a little more convenient way to do it, by subclassing the UITextField and add an @IBInspectable inset property.

```
import UIKit

class UITextfieldWithInset: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable
    var textfieldInset: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)

    override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds, textfieldInset.x, textfieldInset.y)
    }

    override func editingRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds, textfieldInset.x, textfieldInset.y)
    }

    override func placeholderRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectInset(bounds, textfieldInset.x, textfieldInset.y)
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a nice answer for `UITextField`, but the question is about `UITextView`