# UITextView custom form

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

Possible to make the custom form of the UITexView? For example ellipse or semi ellipse form.

[image]

or a more complex case

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try

```
atextview.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
atextView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor];
atextView.layer.cornerRadius = 10; //adjust it to change req. shape
```

UPDATE: In case of  change in `contentInSet` check [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19065693/2515572)

Comment: use textkit framework. but it available only in ios 7.0. Before iOS 6, web views were usually the easiest way to render text with mixed styling, such as bold, italics, or even colors. check [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial)

Comment: The recent shape varying content insets. so check core text framework. have a look at [here](http://weblog.invasivecode.com/core-text)

Comment: thanks,but via core text i get read only text or edited from another object

Answer (score -1):

No need for that, just make it transparent and put UIImageView with any image U like underneath it...